# Alphabetize results in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to do [this](http://phphelper.wordpress.com/php-sort-list-alphabetically/) in CodeIgniter. Here's my code I put into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Paibq1eV).

As you can guess, it's not working. I need the view to render the results like this:

- A
- A Client
- A CLIENT 2
- Another Client
- B
- Big Client
- Brother client
- C
- Course I'm a Client
- Coming Over Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$prev_row = '';
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    $first_letter = strtoupper(substr($client['name'], 0, 1));
    if ($first_letter != $prev_row) {
        echo "<h3>$first_letter</h3>";
    }

    echo $client['name'] . "\n";
    $prev_row = $first_letter;
 }
```

Revised answer based on comments, not sure how your array is structured but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I do have $this->db->order_by("clientname"); in my model. However, I need the letters to seperate the different groups. While I have them ordered alphabetically, the client wants A in front of the As, and B in front of the Bs and so forth.

Comment: but how does that automatically put the column headers in?

Comment: Could you please explain further?

Comment: the table fields are $id, $clientname, and $firstletter. $firstletter is the field the client populates with what category they want the name to go under, for example A, B, or C.

Comment: What I was hoping to do was go through the list of clients. In between the clients that begin with A and the clients that begin with B it would place a 'B'. Then between the clients that begin with B and those that begin with C it would place a C. That's why I was referencing that link, because they did something just like what I wanted to do, but was unable to make work in CI.

Comment: Revised answer, let me know how that goes

Comment: It doesn't render anything, the column collapses. I am working along that same path and my code looks like this but i'm getting a syntax error: http://pastebin.com/ZGLiq7aj

Comment: It works fine for me locally with a hardcoded array. Can you please var_dump($clients);

Comment: here you go:  object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#18 (7) { ["conn_id"]=>  resource(30) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=>  resource(43) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=>  array(0) { } ["result_object"]=>  array(0) { } ["current_row"]=>  int(0) ["num_rows"]=>  int(20) ["row_data"]=>  NULL }

Comment: Ok well you to replace $clients with whatever variable is holding all your client data. You need to go back into your model/controller and make sure you're passing the right data to your view.

Comment: did you see the code I posted to pastebin? I almost have it working except for a syntax error near the else statement?

Comment: Try writing it with traditional syntax rather than the alternate syntax. if() {..} etc. Will be easier to debug, what is the syntax error

Comment: I ended up doing it a different way. Not the way I really wanted but I had to get it done for the client somehow and in the end, that way worked. I had another obstacle waiting for me in that I needed to split the output in between two DIVs on the page. I'm sure your answer would have worked so I gave you credit for it. At least you tried. :)